# Is it efficient to design chat/likes/relationship database in separate table per user?

Tags: database-design, cockroachdb

The specs:

- there would be about 1 billion users
- there would be probably 1 million topics
- each topics has subtopics stored at the same level as topics
- user has many to many relationship with topics (whether they like the topics or not)
- user can chat with another user

The table design:

- 1 table for `users`
- 1 table for `topics`
- N tables for storing users that like a topic (`user_id`, `topic_id`), with naming:
  users_of_`topic_id`
- N tables for storing topics that liked by a user (`user_id`, `topic_id`), with naming:
  topics_of_`user_id`
- NxM tables for `chats` (lower`user_id`, higher`user_id`), with naming:
  chats_[lower`user_id`]_[higher`user_id`]
- N+M tables for chat reference tables, storing table names of the `chats` and their relationships), with naming:
  relations_[`user_id`]

So if we want to match topics between users, we can use `intersect` between topics_of_[`user1`] and topics_of_[`user2`]

If we want to give suggested topics, we can `intersect` random row from users_of_[friend's`topic_id`]

If we want to suggest a mutual friend, we can `union all` relations_[friends`user_id`] then sum it.

Is this design efficient?

**EDIT** apparently this is a job for graph database (such as [dgraph](http://dgraph.io) or [neo4j](https://neo4j.com/))

Comment: `1 billion users`? For real? I admire your optimism. Have you used a search engine for "chat app schema" or similar?

Comment: optimist indeed XD thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. That won’t scale.
Every user and every topic in a separate table would cost an enormous overhead.
Smarter would be a users table that has all user id’s and a topics table that has all topics is’s. 
Next to that you would probably want to have user properties like names and topic properties. They all simply link by their id.
The indexes would give quick access.
If joins are not fast enough for your use case, you might want to use materialized views or snapshots that present the joins for even quicker accesss but don’t be to quick with pre-optimizations, they might not be needed and shoot you in the foot at the end.

Comment: even when using `cockroachdb`?

Comment: ah they said it would slowdown after 1k-10k tables using `cockroachdb`